# Unbind Alt, Ctrl, Caps_lock,etc from pySimpleGUI multiline

Tags: tkinter, pysimplegui

I have a multiline that is being used as an input and output for a terminal app. It sends each character the user types to a second function I've written, then deletes it from the multiline.  My problem is that when I press Shift, Caps Lock, Alt, Ctrl, etc. it triggers the multiline event. Since these don't print any characters in the multiline, it tries to send my previous-last character to the second function, which is not what I need it to do.  How can I allow users to type normally in the multiline (including capital letters when using shift and caps) but have it ignore the keypresses of the special keys?

I tried `window['-ML-'].unbind('<Caps_Lock>')` and `window['-ML-'].unbind('Caps_Lock')` but neither work. I'm pulling this value "Caps_Lock" from the [keysyms](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/keysyms.html) that this [pysimplegui page](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/#binding-tkiner-events) recommends.

Here is a simple example code. Note that when you run the code, since the  multiline is not in focus, the event is listed correctly (i.e. "Caps_Lock:20") but if you clck inside the multiline to put it in focus, pressing any of the special keys triggers an -ML- event (which is what I call my multi line).

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def main():
  
    layout = [[sg.Button ('Clear Data'),sg.Multiline(key='-ML-', size=(100, 20), horizontal_scroll=True, enable_events=True)],]
    window = sg.Window('window', layout, resizable=True, finalize=True, return_keyboard_events=True)
  
#must unbind control, alt, shift, caps lock kets from the text area: 
    window['-ML-'].unbind('<Caps_Lock>')

    while True:
        event, values = window.read( timeout=1000)

        # for debugging
        if "TIMEOUT" not in event:
            sg.popup(event)           
        
        if event == 'Clear Data':
                window['-ML-'].update("")

    window.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Maybe just check if the content of Multiline element changed, or not,

Comment: I usually check the last character in the `values` dictionary to get the actual contents of the `Multiline`, the length of the `Multiline`, and then take some kind of action.  You need to add logic to check for something.  You can look at the last value to see if it's the same for example. Lots of directions you can go.

Comment: The multiline gets updated from stdout as well. Checking for this each time the user enters a character will get time consuming the longer it is used.

Comment: May have trouble after a million characters.........................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may work only under my WIN10 because `e.char` is empty string if Key is a special key, like

- `Shift_L`, `Shift_R`
- `Control_L`, `Control_R`
- `Alt_L`, `Alt_R`
- `Caps_Lock`
- else.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button ('Clear Data')],
    [sg.Multiline(size=(40, 5), key='-ML-')],
]
window = sg.Window('window', layout, finalize=True)
window['-ML-'].bind("<Key>", "")

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Clear Data':
        window['-ML-'].update("")
    elif event == '-ML-':
        e = window['-ML-'].user_bind_event
        if e.char:
            print(e.char)

window.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Jason!  That worked a treat on my Win 10. I'll try to test on linux when I get the chance.